# RecyclerView skips the first few views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` skips views and when it first loads up It makes all the views  the same object in the array until I scroll down and back up then they start to appear. I don't see the problem because it does work, it just does not work as it should. I am using `Volley` to make the network calls.

```
public class ForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JSONParser jsonParser = JSONParser.getJsonParser();
    ForecastListItem[] mArrayList;


    TextView mForecastCityandCountyText;
    String mForecastCityandContryString;
    String mForecastCityNameString;
    String mForecastCountryString;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forcast);
        initializeUI();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        netWorkRequest();
    }


    public void initializeUI() {
        mForecastCityandCountyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ForecastCityName);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Recylerviewlayout);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mArrayList = new ForecastListItem[10];
        mArrayList[0] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[1] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[2] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[3] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[4] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[5] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[6] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[7] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[8] = new ForecastListItem();
        mArrayList[9] = new ForecastListItem();
    }


    public void netWorkRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest JsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonParser.getForecastUrl(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    String UniverSalIconString;
                    Log.d(jsonParser.getForecastUrl(), "");

                    JSONObject mJsonCityObject = response.getJSONObject("city");
                    Log.d("here is the object", mJsonCityObject.toString());

                    mForecastCityNameString = jsonParser.getString("name", mJsonCityObject);
                    mForecastCountryString = jsonParser.getString("country", mJsonCityObject);
                    mForecastCityandContryString = mForecastCityNameString + "," + mForecastCountryString;
                    mForecastCityandCountyText.setText(mForecastCityandContryString);

                    //*********************************************************************************************************************************************
                    // add all the information to arraylist so i can be processed by recycler view
                    // add refresh button
                    JSONArray JsonListArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("list", response);

                    JSONObject Day1 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day1);
                    mArrayList[0].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj));
                    JSONArray JsonDay1WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day1);
                    JSONObject Day1WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay1WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day1WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[0].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day1WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[0].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[0].setMYNUMBER(1);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day2 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(1, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj2 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day2);
                    mArrayList[1].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj2));
                    JSONArray JsonDay2WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day2);
                    JSONObject Day2WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay2WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day2WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[1].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day2WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[1].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[1].setMYNUMBER(2);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day3 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(2, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj3 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day3);
                    mArrayList[2].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj3));
                    JSONArray JsonDay3WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day3);
                    JSONObject Day3WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay3WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day3WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[2].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day3WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[2].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[2].setMYNUMBER(3);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day4 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(3, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj4 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day4);
                    mArrayList[3].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj4));
                    JSONArray JsonDay4WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day4);
                    JSONObject Day4WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay4WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day4WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[3].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day4WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[3].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[3].setMYNUMBER(4);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day5 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(4, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj5 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day5);
                    mArrayList[4].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj5));
                    JSONArray JsonDay5WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day5);
                    JSONObject Day5WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay5WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day5WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[4].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day5WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[4].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[4].setMYNUMBER(5);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day6 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(5, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj6 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day6);
                    mArrayList[5].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj6));
                    JSONArray JsonDay6WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day6);
                    JSONObject Day6WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay6WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day6WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[5].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day6WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[5].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[5].setMYNUMBER(6);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day7 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(6, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj7 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day7);
                    mArrayList[6].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj7));
                    JSONArray JsonDay7WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day7);
                    JSONObject Day7WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay7WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day7WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[6].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day7WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[6].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[6].setMYNUMBER(7);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day8 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(7, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj8 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day8);
                    mArrayList[7].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj8));
                    JSONArray JsonDay8WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day8);
                    JSONObject Day8WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay8WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day8WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[7].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day8WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[7].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[7].setMYNUMBER(8);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day9 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(8, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj9 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day9);
                    mArrayList[8].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj9));
                    JSONArray JsonDay9WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day9);
                    JSONObject Day9WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay9WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day9WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[8].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day9WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[8].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[8].setMYNUMBER(9);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;


                    JSONObject Day10 = jsonParser.getJSONObject(9, JsonListArray);
                    JSONObject TempObj10 = jsonParser.getJSONObject("temp", Day10);
                    mArrayList[9].setmForecastTempDouble(jsonParser.getDouble("day", TempObj10));
                    JSONArray JsonDay10WeatherArray = jsonParser.getJSONArray("weather", Day10);
                    JSONObject Day10WeatherJsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONObject(0, JsonDay10WeatherArray);
                    UniverSalIconString = jsonParser.getString("icon", Day10WeatherJsonObject);
                    mArrayList[9].setmForecastDescriptionString(jsonParser.getString("description", Day10WeatherJsonObject));
                    mArrayList[9].setmForecastIconUrl(jsonParser.getCurrentWeatherIconUrl(UniverSalIconString));
                    mArrayList[9].setMYNUMBER(10);
                    UniverSalIconString = null;

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(JsonObjectRequest);
    }
  class ListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView DescriptionText;
        TextView TempText;
        TextView DateText;
        NetworkImageView ForecastIconImageView;

        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        public ListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            DescriptionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ForcastWeatherDescriptionText);
            TempText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ForecastWeatherTempText);
            ForecastIconImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ForecastWeatherIconImageview);

            // DateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DateText);
        }


        void OnBind(ForecastListItem item) {


            DescriptionText.setText(item.getmForecastDescriptionString());
            TempText.setText(Integer.toString(item.getmForecastTempDouble()));
//            DateText.setText(item.getmForecastDateString());
            ForecastIconImageView.setImageUrl(item.getmForecastIconUrl(), imageLoader);

        }


    }


    class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListHolder> {


        @Override
        public ListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            ListHolder listHolder = new ListHolder(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.forecast_item_view, parent, false));
            return listHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ListHolder holder, int position) {

            Log.d("ARRAY NUM", Integer.toString(mArrayList[position].getMYNUMBER()));
            holder.OnBind(mArrayList[position]);

            // send the array to ViewHolder to set up the UI


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {


            return mArrayList.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: most of the code is the same i just want someone to look at my viewholder class and adapter and see if they see anything wrong

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that you set your `RecyclerView` adapter before making the network call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: thank you for your time and reply "Pztar"

Comment: no it was not that but thank you anyway much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you initialise your adapter with some placeholder data (mArrayList), then you kick off a network request to fetch the data and you update the original arraylist of data.

A better way would be to show an empty list at first and then only when you download the data actually show it in the list.

Also when you download the data you should call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `ListAdapter` to inform it that the original data has changed.

Your web service is Asynchronous, the call doesn't return straight away until it's finished.

You can still pass the mArrayList variable into the constructor of your ListAdapter and have a reference to it in there. Then add a method to your Adapter e.g.

```
public void updateForcastData(ArrayList<ForecastListItem> newData) { 
    //insert new data into your field here
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //consider using one of the other methods like notifyItemInserted() etc either
}
```

Comment: Ok so where would i populate the array since i was using a field variable which was universal for the class file

Comment: do you have a custom constructor for your ListAdapter?

Comment: No i did not create one

Comment: Because i was planning to use an member variable from the main s

Comment: Main activity hosting the recyclerview

Comment: You can still pass the mArrayList variable into the constructor of your ListAdapter and have a reference to it in there. Then add a method to your Adapter e.g. 

`public void updateForcastData(ArrayList<ForecastListItem> newData) {
    //insert new data into your field here
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //consider using one of the other methods like notifyItemInserted() etc either
}`

Comment: Then you would call that method at the end of your VolleyRequest when you have parsed all your data.

Comment: Yea it actually did sorry i did not get back to u sooner i was away for a bit